# How to deal with vite "?worker" imports, so that VSCode is happy?

Tags: typescript, vite, web-worker

I have a Typescript based, Vite based frontend project, that makes used of Web Workers and has an import of the style:

```
import MyWorker from './workers/MyWorker?worker';
```

The problem, in VSCode, the line gets highlighted with the error:

> Cannot find module './workers/MyWorker?worker' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)

How should I be configuring my project so that this resolves in a way to make VSCode happy?

Couldn't find anything on Typescript and [Vite Static Assets](https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#static-assets).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I didn't dig far enough. According to the [documentation](https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#client-types), I need to add the following to my `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": ["vite/client"]
  }
}
```